# Mutate multiple columns with condition in a map function

Tags: r

I want to create several columns with a ifelse()-condition for multiple dataframes. Here is my example code:

```
df1 <- tibble( 
date = lubridate::today() +0:9,
return= runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 5))

df2 <- tibble( 
date = lubridate::today() +0:9,
return= runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 5))

df3 <- tibble( 
date = lubridate::today() +0:9,
return= runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 5))
```

And now I want to add new columns with ascending conditions (from 1 to 5). The first column should only contain values from the "return"-column, which is higher than 1, the second column should only contain values, which is higher than 1.5, the third column should only contain values, which is higher than 2, and so on...

For example, I can do it with a for-loop. But that works only for one dataframe:

```
for(i in seq(1, 5, 0.5)){
varname =paste0("return>",i)
df1[[varname]] <- with(df1, ifelse(return > i, return, NA))
}

> head(df1)
# A tibble: 6 x 12
date       return `return > 0.5 s~ `return > 1 sd` `return > 1.5 s~ `return > 2 sd` `return > 2.5 s~
<date>      <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
1 2019-03-09  4.94             4.94             4.94             4.94            4.94             4.94
2 2019-03-10  0.936            0.936           NA               NA              NA               NA   
3 2019-03-11  0.770            0.770           NA               NA              NA               NA   
4 2019-03-12  1.03             1.03             1.03            NA              NA               NA   
5 2019-03-13  3.34             3.34             3.34             3.34            3.34             3.34
6 2019-03-14  0.983            0.983           NA               NA              NA               NA   
# ... with 5 more variables: `return > 3 sd` <dbl>, `return > 3.5 sd` <dbl>, `return > 4 sd` <dbl>,
#   `return > 4.5 sd` <dbl>, `return > 5 sd` <dbl>
```

Here is another code to get the desired output for one dataframe:

```
n <- seq(0.5, 5, 0.5)
df1[paste0("return > ", n, " sd")] <- lapply(n, function(x) 
replace(df1$return, df1$return <= x, NA))
```

My question is, how can I put this code in a map-function (or in another function) to run this code for all 3 dataframes?

Comment: you could loop through each dataframe and return a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the dataframes in a list and create a function to return new columns

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

return_new_cols <- function(df1) { 
  n <- seq(0.5, 5, 0.5)
  df1[paste0("return > ", n, " sd")] <- lapply(n, function(x) 
                            replace(df1$return, df1$return <= x, NA))
  df1
}
```

Now apply `return_new_cols` function to each dataframe in the list

```
lapply(df_list, return_new_cols)
```

You can achieve the same with `purrr::map` instead of `lapply`

```
purrr::map(df_list, return_new_cols)
```